# Opening the wall between a kitchen and living room, and install steel beam to support second floor

Tags: framing

The kitchen wall runs east to west 20'-10" in length, with the kitchen on the south side of the wall and living room on the north side of the wall. From west to east the first 24" of wall will remain, the next 5' will be spanned to a column, the next 11'-2" span is open resting on the last 32" of wall existing to remain. From west to east, the first 12" of wall supports the kitchen ceiling, the next 15' of wall supports the second floor and kitchen ceiling, the last 4' supports the ceiling of the kitchen on one side of the wall and living room ceiling on the other side of the wall.

Comment: If your question is what type of beam to install and where, that's definitely something for a structural engineer to recommend, having looked at the actual building.

Comment: You will need a structural engineer to check and make plans for this job, so the house does not fall on you.  Engineer will know the proper size of the beam and how to build the temporary supports for taking down the wall and placing the beam.

Comment: To emphasise @Armand and crip659's posts - this is a safety thing, and a bad decision now could lead to death and/or injury later. It's not just the size of the steel beam itself (and whatever is on top that it's supposed to offload to the sides), but also how that beam will be supported on the remaining structure.

Comment: Not only is there beam size to consider but footings this is an advanced job on a single level home and possible diy with the correct footings and beam size for the load.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no questions have been asked. Even with plans,  we couldn't give an absolute answer. A structural engineer  needs to answer this.

Comment: In editing I removed the question, what size steel beam to install, I had figured a 4" wide 8"deep and 1/4" thick.

Comment: Well, then, at a minimum, [edit] the question back in.

Answer (score 2):

Hire an engineer to design the correct beam, and follow their advice to the letter - or bet your house on some other method.